# getting image from UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I am loading a web page inside a UIWebView, clearly a web page has many images in it. I am loading it to the UIWebView via

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

the issue is that this doesn't trigger the NSURLCached which I have subclassed. I basically want to cache the data I get when the UIWebView loads the `<img src = "">` tag so I can use it later on for faster loading or such. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should actually work. Did you set your cache globally via NSURLCache's

```
+ (void)setSharedURLCache:(NSURLCache *)cache
```

before loading the HTML?

Maybe you would like to have a look at [Matt Gallagher's NSURLCache Tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/substituting-local-data-for-remote.html), which shows an example of a subclassed NSURLCache which does pretty much what you're asking for (serving stored images for certain requests).

Comment: yea, I did read Matt Galagher's tutorial. For some reason my subclassed NSURLCache is not called

Comment: Could you post or link to your code? What you want should be possible, so we should look at your specific implementation.

Comment: actually if you downloaded matts gallagher NSURLCache example and replace it with loadHTMLString instead of loadRequest it won't trigger any of the NSURLCache subclass he wrote, you can try it out

Comment: I did, and it does work: try `[((UIWebView *)self.view) loadHTMLString:@"<img src='http://images.apple.com/global/nav/images/globalnavbg.png' />" baseURL:nil];` instead of the `loadRequest:` call and you should see the replacement image.

Comment: that;s true it works.. wonder why mine doesn't. I basically copied the LocalSubstitutionCache into my project and did a loadHTMLString and then it didn't call the NSURLCache subclass. How do I make it so that it uses the LocalSubstitutionCache?

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your code. If it doesn't call your `cachedResponseForRequest:` method at all you probably didn't set the cache as global shared cache (in the example it's in the AppDelegate).

Comment: ah! it was that code at the delegate.. so if I do this then for every UIWebView it will call the cachedResponseForRequest? Is there a way to limit this?